# SQL Query to get the names of the employees who has won both "Gold" and "silver awards"

Tags: sql

Employee Table:

```
Employee Name   Awards
  A             Gold
  B             Silver
  C             Diamond
  D             Silver
  A             Silver
  B             Diamond
```

I want the names of the employees who has won both "Gold" and "silver awards"

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 @TheImpaler

Comment: SELECT Employee from EmployeeTable WHERE Awards LIKE "Gold" OR Awards LIKE "SILVER" ;

Answer (score 3):

You could use this:

```
SELECT employee_name   
FROM employee 
WHERE awards IN ('Gold', 'Silver')
GROUP BY employee_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT awards) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post the relevant part of your database schema. Is this the only table? The real answer is to read up on "normalized database" and split this table into three tables: Employees, Awards, and EmployeeAwards to join the other two many-to-many.

Comment: Without additional info there's no *real answer*.